# How to make 18000 into 18,000.00 as an output? Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

I have data 18000 in my database and the datatype is decimal but the length of decimal is empty. How do I make it into 18,000.00 as an output?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, i tried to put (3,2) as length in decimals, but there's an error

Comment: both of the answers below do exactly what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function here.

```
$number = 18000;

$formatted_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', ','); // Gives 18,000.00
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>[FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format)</kbd> function in `mysql`.

**Query**

```
SELECT FORMAT(18000, 2);
```

**Result**

```
18,000.00
```

Comment: This depend on the locale, which happens to have dot and comma.  (US-centric, I guess)